# Office web addin addin command send command to taskpane

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins

When the user clicks a button in the ribbon, I want to open the taskbar (when it is not opened already) and then I want to execute code depending on which button in the ribbon was clicked.

I m using vue.js for the taskpane.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but it's a suggestion that's too complicated to put into a comment:

For each button, add the `<ExtensionPoint>` and `<Control>` markup in the add-in's manifest. Details are in [Create Add-in Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands). Set the Action type to `ShowTaskpane` for all the buttons. For each of the actions, set the `<SourceLocation>`'s `resid` to a different string. Then in the `<Resources><Urls>` section, set each of the resid strings to the URL of the taskpane page, but have a *different query parameter* on the end of each of them.

```
<bt:Urls>
    <bt:Url id="residButton1" DefaultValue="https://contoso.com/Home.aspx?Button1">
    <bt:Url id="residButton2" DefaultValue="https://contoso.com/Home.aspx?Button2" />
</bt:Url>
```

Then have startup logic in the taskpane page that reads the query parameter to determine which button was pressed. The startup logic can be in a function assigned to `Office.initialize` or in a callback to `Office.onReady`.

Comment: Ok thank you. I have thought about that too. I just hope that there is a way without reloading the page. Like the buttons are firing an event or so for that I can subscribe wirh my taskpane

Comment: Oh just realized that that can not be possible because, in Word desktop, the ribbon buttons aren't Html buttons