# Open taskpane using runtime URL from ExecuteFuntion in office 365 word addin

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I am working on an Office 365 Word addin. I have 2 buttons (Display and Search) on the ribbon.

When clicking the "Display" button, I pass the selected word to my application with a query param and open in task pane, for example:

```
http://www.myapplication.com?display=[selectedword]
```

When clicking on the "Search" button, I pass selected word to my application with a query param and open in task pane, for example:

```
http://www.myapplication.com?search=[selectedword]
```

To get the selected word I am using `ExecuteFunction` and based on the selected word I append `queryParam` to my application URL.

```
    Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(
                function (result) {
                    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                        onError(result.error);
                    }
                    else {
                       var finalURLToOpenInTaskPane = [myApplicationURL] + '?display=' + result.value;

//TODO Open this URL in taskpane
                    }
                }
            );
```

I am not sure how can I open this URL with query param in task pane from this `ExecuteFunction`.

I have tried the below link but in which he is not using query param but he directly uses static URL.

[Office web addin addin command send command to taskpane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56313927/office-web-addin-addin-command-send-command-to-taskpane)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The URL for the taskpane has to be in the manifest. You can't set it at runtime. I recommend that you design your add-in to use buttons in the task pane instead of buttons on the ribbon.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In the task pane, I want to open my application http://www.myapplication.com?display=[selectedword] with selected tax as a query param. So if I put a button on the task pane then how can I open my application in the task pane and also how can I go back once I open my application in taskpane.Thanks in Advance

Comment: You won't be able to open your application the way that you want. Have a button on the ribbon that opens the add-in. Have a button on the task pane that gets the selected word.

Comment: One last quick query. If I use VSTO word addin, Can we set/configure some labels, icons, and buttons as we do in the office 365 word addin's manifest.xml file OR do we have any other way so users can set labels and icons as they want?

Comment: I don't know about VSTO add-ins. I recommend creating a new Stack Overflow question and tagging it `vsto`.